# Image Captioning with pytorch: outputs are getting negative and loss is getting negative

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I am new to Image Captioning and write some code according to examples, but my loss is getting more and more negative. Maybe something wrong with the model. Here is the code:

```
class CNNEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size):
        super(CNNEncoder, self).__init__()
        resnet = models.resnet50(pretrained = True)
        for param in resnet.parameters():
            param.requires_grad_(False)

        modules = list(resnet.children())[:-1]
        self.resnet = nn.Sequential(*modules)
        self.embed = nn.Linear(resnet.fc.in_features, embed_size)
        self.batch= nn.BatchNorm1d(embed_size, momentum = 0.01)
        self.embed.weight.data.normal_(0., 0.02)
        self.embed.bias.data.fill_(0)


        # self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        # self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

    def forward(self, input):
        features = self.resnet(input)
        features = features.view(features.size(0), -1)
        features = self.batch(self.embed(features))
        return features
```

```
class DecoderRNN(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, embed_size, hidden_size, vocab_size):
    super(DecoderRNN, self).__init__()
    self.embed = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_size, padding_idx=vocabulary.get_index("<pad>"))
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embed_size, hidden_size, batch_first=True)
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)

    self.init_weights()

  def init_weights(self):
    """Initialize weights."""
    self.embed.weight.data.uniform_(-0.1, 0.1)
    self.linear.weight.data.uniform_(-0.1, 0.1)
    self.linear.bias.data.fill_(0)

  def forward(self, features, captions):
    embeddings = self.dropout(self.embed(captions))
    embeddings = torch.cat((features.unsqueeze(1), embeddings),
                                                        dim=1)
    # print(embeddings.shape)
    hiddens, _ = self.lstm(embeddings)
    outputs = self.linear(hiddens[:,-1])


    return outputs
```

```
class Encoder_Decoder(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, embed_size, hidden_size, vocab_size):
    super(Encoder_Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.cnn = CNNEncoder(embed_size)
    self.decoderRNN = DecoderRNN(embed_size, hidden_size,
                                 vocab_size)

  def forward(self, images, captions):
    features = self.cnn(images)
    outputs = self.decoderRNN(features, captions)
    return outputs
```

For the training I have created sequences of words, such that the model gets image and sequence as input, and has a next word from sequence as a target. Maybe that is wrong. Hope for some help.

I tried to look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2BaTt1fxJU) and [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/solving-an-image-captioning-task-using-deep-learning/) but can't find the answer.

Comment: A loss is supposed to minimize, if it is going further and further negative then the optimizer is doing its job. It also appears your whole code isn't posted, as I was looking for your optimizer and noticed that you posted your architectures, but not the code to run them. And what do you mean your outputs are going negative?